# Skew-selfadjointness of commutator of self-adjoint unbounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

In the Hilbert space $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ let the two operators $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ be defined by:
$$ \hat x f(x) := x f(x),~ \hat p f(x) := -i \frac{d f(x)}{dx}. $$

Then let the commutator be defined on a maximal domain as: $$ [\hat x,\hat p] : D_{[\hat x,\hat p]} \rightarrow L^2 (\mathbb{R}), [\hat x,\hat p] :=  \hat x \hat p -\hat p \hat x, \\ D_{[\hat x,\hat p]} := \displaystyle{\{f(x) \in L^2 (\mathbb R) | \int_{\mathbb R} \left[(\hat x \hat p -\hat p \hat x)f(x)\right]^{*}  \left[(\hat x \hat p -\hat p \hat x)f(x)\right] dx < +\infty \}}. $$

**Question**: Is the commutator skew-selfadjoint? If so, what is a proof of this? If not, then is it skew-essentially self-adjoint? As far as I know, the Schwartz test function space $\mathcal S (\mathbb R) $ is an essential (skew) self-adjointness domain, which is clearly a proper subset of the commutator's maximal domain, to that can't be.

Comment: Note that $x$ and $p$ are not defined on all of $L^2$ - in particular the compositions $xp-px$ are not always defined. The way you have defined the maximal domain is also not entirely correct. But to be more concrete, if you do everything correctly you find that $xp-px$ is equal to $i\Bbb 1$ and you can get as maximal domain all of $L^2$.

Comment: @s.harp 1 is clearly bounded and everywhere defined, but the commutator is unbounded, provided it exists (well for x and p it does, for the Schwartz test function space is a common dense everywhere invariant subset of the maximal domains of x and p). I am just looking for a proof that on the maximal domain of the commutator the operator is self-adjont. And why is this maximal domain wrong the way I defined it?